# Compared with Envoy and Apache APISIX, which one is more suitable for service mesh selection?

Tags: gateway, api-gateway, envoyproxy, servicemesh, apache-apisix

Want to select a service mesh, currently concerned about Envoy and Apache APISIX, Can any developer who has used both service grids help me to choose ?

Comment: Doesn't look like APISIX is a service mesh.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.